# How do I make "if the loop is executing for the last time" condition in python

Tags: python, django

So, I am making a login system through file handling in python. The code works fine when I enter the correct username/password but it doesn't work when I use 'else' statement for the condition which should execute when the user enters incorrect password.

```
for line in open('accounts.txt','r+').readlines():
    loginfo = line.split()
    if a==loginfo[0] and b==loginfo[1]:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

- Here, the loop is executed and each line is checked to see if the username, password entered by the user is in the file or not.
- I am using getlines() function to get usernames and passwords of a user through lines, which means each line should consist of a username and password separated with a space.
- I am using line.split to split usernames and passwords in the file.
- If I remove "else" then enter the correct password, then the code works fine but it does not work fine when I enter incorrect password.
- If I put 'else' condition inside the loop then it messes up the algorithm, and the web-page is rendered when the loop is executing for the first time.
- What I want is that the "else" condition should execute only and the web-page 'index.html' should only be displayed when the file is completely checked (which means that the for loop is executing for the last time) and the username/password entered by the user is not found in the file.

Comment: You're returning regardless on the first iteration of the for loop so it'll only check the first line

Comment: Using plain-text files for login in a Django app ??? Are you serious ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for line in file:  
    loginfo = line.strip().split()
    if a==loginfo[0] and b==loginfo[1]:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Note :- this should be applied for `distinct usernames`

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct? You are still returning unconditionally in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: thanks @rtoijala, i pushed it inside while formatting for code.

Comment: I have updated the code, please check again @FahadAzeem

Comment: You don't need a flag at all - you can just return from the `if` block in the loop.

Comment: @Exprator I perfectly understand the question, thanks. And I repeat: you don't need a flag at all.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a flag nor a distinct function here:

```
# use a with block to ensure the file will be properly closed
with open("accounts.txt") as file:
    # files are their own iterators, no need to read the
    # whole file in memory
    for line in file:
        # get rid of newlines / trailing whitespaces etc
        loginfo = line.strip().split()
        if a==loginfo[0] and b==loginfo[1]:
            return render(request, 'login.html')

    # if a match has been found, we'll never get here,
    # so if we get here no match has been found...
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Now I have to say that storing login data in a text file is the worst idea ever, specially when Django as a full, safe, working, and very easy to use auth/user system.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file has a lot of lines, and each one matches a specific account. The error you are doing is that you return `False` inside the loop, which is wrong because you have to loop through all the lines. After that you can just return `False` because no account matches the login and the password

```
def check_login():
    for line in open('accounts.txt','r+').readlines():
        loginfo = line.split()
        if a==loginfo[0] and b==loginfo[1]:
            return True
    return False

def login_view(request):
    if check_login():
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```